# Finite difference coefficients in more than 1 dimension.

Tags: numerical-methods, finite-differences

Computing the finite difference coefficients of an arbitrary 1D stencil with varying set of samples and derivative order is well known:

- [Cameron Taylor's Finite Difference Calculator with Theory](https://web.media.mit.edu/%7Ecrtaylor/calculator.html)
- [Wikipedia - Finite Difference Coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference_coefficient)

Yet, these do not include multidimensional stencils such as the 5-point stencil in 2D and 7-point stencil in 3D.

As an example, the 5-point von Neumann stencil in 2D can be defined as the following pairs of samples: [[0, 0], [-1, 0], [1, 0], [0, -1], [0, 1]] and has the following corresponding coefficients: [4, -1, -1, -1, -1].

Abuse-of-notation boolean matrix of the stencil:
$$\begin{pmatrix}
 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 
 0 & 1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$$
The corresponding coefficients:
$$\begin{pmatrix}
 0 & -1 & 0 \\ 
 -1 & 4 & -1 \\ 
 0 & -1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$$

Is there a formula generalizing the finite difference coefficients to arbitrary dimensions?

Comment: Just put $-1$s along the edges and $2n$ in the middle.

Comment: I am looking for the general solution not just the 5-point stencil. It should also work e.g. for the Moore stencil:
$$\begin{pmatrix}
 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 
 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 
 1 & 1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$$
It has to generalize the arbitrary sample and arbitrary order method Cameron Taylor presents to arbitrary dimensions.